# Why won't my TextView add to RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to add my textView to my app programmatically, but it doesn't appear when I run it.I put  a button in the XML to test the relativeLayout and it appears fine, but the textView doesn't so I'm putting down to code? my code is below. Thanks in advance!

```
       @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    StringX = response;
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response);

                    TextView valueTV = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                    valueTV.setText("Hello!");
                    valueTV.setTextSize(20);
                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);
                 valueTV.setTextColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 95, 0));
                    valueTV.setId(0);
                    scrollerF.addView(valueTV);
                }
```

And my layout:

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.garethpower92.tourlink_ireland.coupons">


<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/scrollerMain"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlX"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Discounts"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="#009500"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is scrollerF?  If its a relative layout (I assume as you're using RelativeLayout LayoutParams) you probably want to add rules describing where to put it  Otherwise its probably being covered by some other view.

Comment: oh okay, how do i do that?

Comment: It really depends on what the layout is like  and where you want it to go. The rules are things like you'd add in relative layout xml-  layout_above, layout_alignParentBottom, etc.  To add one you use addRule(int verb, int target), where verb is the constant for the rule type you want and target is any id the rule is relative to.  You can add as many rules as needed, so long as the combo of all rules is legal.

Comment: What is scrollerF scrollerMain or the realative?

Comment: Okay, I'll try, Thanks

Comment: motis10 rlX is the relative layout which I add it to, scrollerF is findviewById(R.id.rlX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code works for me,
In your activity onCreate method add this code:

```
    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      TextView mTextv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
      mTextv.setText("This is Text....!!");
      mTextv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
      linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lLayout);
        mTextv.setTextSize(20);
      mTextv.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
      mTextv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454045"));
        linearLayout.addView(mTextv);
 }
```

Linear layout is the parent layout of TextView you'll add dynamically, so ad textview as child view in  linearLayout object.

Comment: Happy to Help you @garethpower

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
     TextView valueTV = new TextView(scrollerF.getContext());
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    valueTV.setLayoutParams(params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT));
                    valueTV.setText("Hello!");
                    valueTV.setTextSize(20);
         scrollerF.addView(valueTV);
```

`scrollerF.invalidate();`

Comment: please cehck updted ans